# for each row add duplicates with change of 2 cells

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a bunch of rows and I want to append duplicates except change two of the cells.
I need each person to have a row for 15000, 20000, 25000 for each 24 and 36 (if this makes sense?)

Input:

```
        A          B        C         D
1     15000       24      Susan     Smith
2     15000       24      John      Deer
```

Expected output

```
        A          B        C         D
1     15000       24      Susan     Smith
2     20000       24      Susan     Smith
3     25000       24      Susan     Smith
4     15000       36      Susan     Smith
5     20000       36      Susan     Smith
6     25000       36      Susan     Smith
7     15000       24      John      Deer
8     20000       24      John      Deer
9     25000       24      John      Deer
10    15000       36      John      Deer
11    20000       36      John      Deer
12    25000       36      John      Deer
```

I understand that I need to do a function that for each row copies and appends the row, but am unsure how this is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to achieve the conversion in your question.

  - For example, when the values of the columns "C" and "D" are `Susan` and `Smith`, respectively, you want to put the following values to the Spreadsheet.

    ```
      15000       24      Susan     Smith
      20000       24      Susan     Smith
      25000       24      Susan     Smith
      15000       36      Susan     Smith
      20000       36      Susan     Smith
      25000       36      Susan     Smith
    ```
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, I would like to propose the following flow.

1. Retrieve the values from the columns "C" and "D" from the source sheet.
2. Remove the empty rows.
3. Create an array for putting values using the values of `15000, 20000, 25000` and `24, 36` for the columns "A" and "B", respectively.
4. Put the values to the destination sheet.

When above flow is reflected to a Google Apps Script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, please set the variables of `srcSheetName` and `dstSheetName`, and run the function of `myFunction`.

```
function myFunction() {
  const srcSheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the source sheet name.
  const dstSheetName = "Sheet2";  // Please set the destination sheet name.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // 1. Retrieve the values from the columns "C" and "D".
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
  const values = srcSheet.getRange("C1:D" + srcSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  // 2. Remove the empty rows.
  const v = values.filter(([c,d]) => c && d);

  // 3. Create an array for putting values using the values of `15000, 20000, 25000` and `24, 36` for the columns "A" and "B", respectively.
  const colA = [15000, 20000, 25000];
  const colB = [24, 36];
  const res = v.reduce((ar, [c,d]) => {
    colB.forEach(b => colA.forEach(a => ar.push([a, b, c, d])));
    return ar;
  }, []);

  // 4. Put the values to the destination sheet.
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName(dstSheetName);
  dstSheet.getRange(1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

#### Note:

- If you want to use above script as the custom function, you can also use the following script. In this case, please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, please put the custom function of `=SAMPLE(C1:D)` to a cell. By this, the result values are obtained.

  ```
    const SAMPLE = values => values
      .filter(([c,d]) => c && d)
      .reduce((ar, [c,d]) => {
        [24, 36].forEach(b => [15000, 20000, 25000].forEach(a => ar.push([a, b, c, d])));
        return ar;
      }, []);
  ```

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)